# Vectorize for loop over two rows with condition

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

I want to perform some operations on my dataframe, but I have some problems with performance, so I was wondering how I could speed up the performance of  my code.
My data has several columns and if the column X is 0, I want to do some operations on other columns (adding and max). If X is 1, do nothing (X can only be 1 or 0)

```
df <- data.frame(X = c(0,0,1,0,1),Y = c(10,0,0,3,7),Z = c(2,2,0,4,5)) 


   df
  X  Y Z
1 0 10 2
2 0  0 2
3 1  0 0
4 0  3 4
5 1  7 5
```

Right now my code looks like:

```
for(i in 1:(nrow(df)-1)){
  if(df$X[i] == 0){
    df$Y[i+1] <- df$Y[i]+df$Y[i+1]
    df$Z[i+1] <- max(df$Z[i],df$Z[i+1])
  }
}
```

The result should look like:

```
df
  X  Y Z
1 0 10 2
2 0 10 2
3 1 10 2
4 0  3 4
5 1 10 5
```

Is there a way to write this more efficiently?
Additionally, a lot of the rows contain only 0's, so I was wondering if there is an efficient way to skip the operations for these rows, as the value won't change.

Edit:
As I was a bit unspecific about the rules, here they are in greater detail:
Y should get summed up until there is 1 again (the sum (including the value for the row, where the 1 is) should replace the value of the row with the 1). The same principle should be applied to the X variable, but this time with the max() function.

Many thanks!

Comment: Could you please edit your post to include a larger sample `data.frame`? One that has multiple `1` entries in column `A`, and that is representative of your larger dataset.

Comment: I edited the question. I hope I is clearer now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this? This reproduces your expected output:

```
df <- data.frame(X = c(0,0,1,0,1),Y = c(10,0,0,3,7),Z = c(2,2,0,4,5))

df %>%
    mutate(
        group = cumsum(c(0, diff(X) == -1))) %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(
        n = 1:n(),
        Y = cumsum(Y),
        Z = ifelse(n > 1, max(Z, lead(Z, default = 0)), Z)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(X, Y, Z)
#    # A tibble: 5 x 3
#      X     Y     Z
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    0.   10.    2.
#2    0.   10.    2.
#3    1.   10.    2.
#4    0.    3.    4.
#5    1.   10.    5.
```

Explanation: Group entries based on `0`-series terminated by `1`; replace `Y` with the `cumsum` of `Y`; replace `Z` with the maximum of entries in that row and from the next row, starting from the second row (`n > 1`).

Comment: Maybe add something like `group_by(cumsum(lag(X, default = 0)))`?

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I can only apply the functions until the next 1 is in the X cell, so Maurits answer won't work

Comment: @EconFin So what's wrong with your code? Why do you think your code is inefficient?

Comment: I cannot execute due to the lack of computing power (the original file has 1.2m rows and has to do these operations on 7 columns). Since I am quite new to R, I was thinking that the code might be inefficient in some sence (as I don't have the knowledge about R to know that this is not the case). However, thank you for your effort!

Comment: @EconFin If you're interested and to get a rough idea on memory usage and efficiency, have a look [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html). I'll have a think about your problem; I'm sure there is a more efficient way.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I will have a look at it!

Comment: @EconFin I've updated my solution; please take a look. While this reproduces your expected output, I'm not sure how robust my solution is for more general cases.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tested it and it seems good. It is also much faster in terms of computation time! Your answer was great help to me!

Comment: @EconFin Great, glad it helped!